# JavaScript sourcemap 404 error as source not web accessible

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gruntjs, source-maps

I use [grunt-contrib-coffee](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee/) to generate my source maps and they all point to the correct location of the source `.coffeescript` files but they 404 as the `/app/` folder is above the webroot which is `/dist/`.

Directory structure:

```
/app/
 |--scripts/script1.coffee
 |--scripts/script2.coffee
/dist/ (webroot)
 |--scripts/script1.js
 |--scripts/script2.js
Gruntfile.js
```

This is the generated map file.

```
"version": 3,
  "file": "script1.js",
  "sourceRoot": "../app/scripts/",
  "sources": [
    "script1.coffee"
  ]
```

The browser is looking for `GET http://0.0.0.0:9000/app/scripts/app.coffee 404 (Not Found)` but won't find it because it's not web accessible.

Should I make my webroot the same as the Gruntfile.js location? I don't want to end up with a trailing `/dist/` on the URL

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: The only solution is to copy the source files into the dist folder as well.